# How to autocomplete the options for a command in SLES 12?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, bash-completion, sles

I have a service, say xyz. As of now, I can start, stop or restart that service using the command rcxyz start, rcxyz stop and rcxyz restart respectively. It is working fine.

All that I want to do is, if I type rcxyz and press `<TAB>`, I would like to have the three options (start, stop and restart) to be auto completed.

I referred the other bash_completion related questions in stackoverflow and tried writing a dummy script `/etc/bash_completion.d/rcxyz.sh` inside which I have written

```
complete -c rcxyz
```

I was expecting that when I type rcxyz and press `<TAB>`, I will get the list of available commands as argument. But it didn't work.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write:

```
complete -W 'start stop restart' rcxyz
```

See bash's manual:

> -W *wordlist*
>
> > The  *wordlist*  is  split using the characters in the `IFS`
> >                           special variable as delimiters, and each resultant  word
> >                           is  expanded.   The possible completions are the members
> >                           of the resultant list which match the  word  being  completed.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you so much :)